# Pow does not work when wifi is on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ios-simulator, rack-pow

When using the ios-simulator, I cannot reach pow endpoints while my wifi is on. When I turn off my wifi, everything works. Any ideas?

Comment: I think this has to do with a messed up network :(